# Dialogflow confusing intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a basic application using dialog flow and noticed that it keeps confusing the intents. I have 2 intents, one for buying a car and one for buying a bike.

The car intent has training phrases (Action: buyCar):

```
I would like to buy a car with 4 doors 
I would like to buy a car with 2 doors
The car should have 4 doors
```

The bike intent has training phrases (Action: buyBike):

```
I would like to buy a bike with 400 hp and red color
the bike should have 350 hp and green color
```

I assumed the intents would match based on the type of vehicle (car or bike) and specifically related to the `sys.num + doors` (as defined in my car entity) for cars and `sys.num + hp` and `sys.color` for bikes (as defined in my entities). However when I actually ask it something about a bike.. it takes on the car intent (as it was defined first?)

for instance, if I ask the simulator `I would like to buy a bike with 400 hp and red color` It would assign the action as `buyCar` and assign the vehicle as bike, however since it thinks the action is car, it assigns the `sys.num + doors` as `400 hp`.

I cannot seem to figure out how to stop it from getting confused.. I realise intents are matched based vaguely on keywords, but is it possible to specifically match only on these keywords and based on the number of variables required? so 1 var would be car, 2 vars would be bike.

Comment: If you can post screenshots of your intents showing the sample phrases and parameters that you're using, that will help us diagnose the problem. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151841/1405634 which may have had the same problem.

Comment: That solution helped a lot. I was able to change my dialogflow following that solution. Instead of matching based on vehicle type, I hardcoded the vehicle in and now I match base don the action name (on my backend). Thanks for the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actions-on-Google: Similar intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128756/actions-on-google-similar-intents)

Comment: If the answer there helped, upvoting it is always appreciated. I wasn't sure if it was similar to what you needed. Since it is, I'll vote to close this one as a duplicate.